# MASM x86 Assembly print string function

Tags: function, assembly, masm

(I am relatively new to the assembly language so it might be a really obvious question, sorry)

I am trying to write a function in x86 assembly (Visual Studio, MASM, Windows 10) that I can call from C which takes in a char* and prints it.

So far I have this code for the function:

```
_scuffed_printf PROC

    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    <???>

    pop ebp
    ret

_scuffed_printf ENDP
```

Is there any way to achieve this without having to use Windows API functions like MessageBox?

Comment: Are you linking against the C library?  You can pass the string to `fputs(string_arg, stdout)`, or to `printf("%s", string_arg)`.  (It's not safe to just `jmp printf` tailcall because the string might include `%` characters.  But if you don't mind appending a newline, you could replace your whole function with `jmp puts`)

Comment: Yes I am linking against the C library, in fact what I want is to write an entirely new function purely in assembly which does not rely on any other existing functions like printf or puts. Is this a possibility in Windows?

Comment: Yes, of course you can call native Windows functions exported by Windows DLLs, like WriteFile to do IO on stdout.  (Windows doesn't have a documented / stable `syscall` interface to call directly into the kernel the way you can on Linux.  Of course you *can* use raw system calls on Windows, since people have reverse engineered the DLLs, but the call numbers can vary between windows kernel versions)